# How to start my motorcycle when the kick-starter fails?

Tags: motorcycle, starting

This morning I tried to start my motorcycle but the ***kick-starter*** failed. It was idle for about a month but it was riding fine before that . My motorcycle doesn't have an electric starter function.

The fuel tank has more than a liter of petrol, last I checked. And, the battery is 3 years old.

With kick-start being the only option , how can I start my motorcycle , so that I can take it to the nearest mechanic for repair ?

I own a BAJAJ CT100, which is a 100cc motorcycle.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the kick-starter failed"? Did it physically break, or do you mean you simply couldn't start it with the kick starter?

Comment: Could be bad gas, if it's been sitting around for a while. The hydrocarbons clump together and make it hard to burn. Get some octane booster and see if it helps, or remove the fuel and put fresh stuff in.

Comment: I meant to say I couldn't start my motorcycle with the kick-starter @TMN

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Turn the key in the ignition to 'On'
- Hold the clutch lever
- Engage first or second gear
- Let the motorcycle gain speed (either go downhill or push start)
- Let go of the clutch lever. The motorcycle should sputter to life

Comment: Probably a good idea to be sitting on the bike when doing this :)

Comment: @HandyHowie and facing forwards :D

Comment: With a small bike, you don't have to be sitting on it, but yea, it's normally a good idea.  If you're feeling adventurous and want to run beside the bike you can pull the clutch back in as you feel the engine start.

Comment: I don't know about a 100cc bike but I knew a guy who had to bump start his Hornet 600 on a regular basis till he got a new battery, that could be done at a fast walking pace while paddling the bike along.

Comment: My 750 Nighthawk I can get going on a small hill in first gear, but my Superhawk is 1000cc and I need a decent hill and second gear for that.  4 tiny cylinders vs 2 huuuge ones...

Comment: a few of us have gotten a volvo bus started like this in some parts of the world

Comment: Depending on traction available from road and tire, it may be necessary to instead use third gear and push to a higher speed. If the battery is very low, and/or the alternator does not provide sufficient power at idle to run bike, you may need to keep RPM's a little bit higher to charge the battery for a bit--on an air cooled bike, make sure to not do this for long, and starting riding it ASAP to let it charge while riding without overheating. As a 165 lb guy, I push started a 550 lb 1250cc (4 cyl) 1986 for the better part of a year. Not fun, but definitely doable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a drill to start most pull start or kick start engines. be sure not to let go. It's not the safest idea but for a temporary use it will get you home

Comment: warning - this can give you a mean kickback.  I've removed the crank nut on a small engine doing this.

Comment: Or brake a wrist on a serious note not safe

Comment: @Michael, how does one brake a wrist?

Comment: If your not holding the drill right trying to start an engine. It can twist your wrist up pretty good from the torque.

Answer (score -2):

It is very likely a battery issue.  Put your battery on a battery tender and trickle charge it back to full.

Edit:
Make sure you remove it from your bike first.

Comment: Dead batteries benefit more from a full charge, not a trickle. If they don't take a charge, they're done.