# Starting Enfield with low/dead battery

Tags: engine, motorcycle, starting, battery-drain, enfield-bullet

My bike has a very low/dead battery and it doesn't start. What I did though was, kick the bike for few minutes and later it started, but when I tried to move the vehicle by putting it in first gear it automatically switch off any suggestion on how to start this?

PS : Mechanic or any help is minimum 20km away so any suggestion on fixing this vehicle on my own?

Comment: Do you have a kickstand switch that grounds out the ignition?  When you have it on the center-stand and you kick start it make sure your kickstand is up.

Answer (score 6):

**Many times you can start a motorcycle with a low battery**

- [This answer has a push start method](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26254/how-to-start-my-motorcycle-when-the-kick-starter-fails/26255#26255)
- You can also coast down a hill and let out the clutch with the ignition 'on' and the start switch set to 'on'
- Use jumper cables and get a charge from a car battery.  You can use the jumper cables and allow the car to just idle.  You don't want to charge your battery too quickly with a high amperage as you can do damage to the battery.  Check your battery temp by touching it occaisionally to get an idea of temperature.  Do not let the battery get hot to the touch.  If it does, allow it to cool for a bit and stop charging it.  As well, you can charge your battery with the car engine off.  You may want to disconnect the car from time to time and start it to keep the car battery from draining too much.

**Things to check**

- Ignition switch w/ key set to 'on'
- Sidestand switch, make sure the sidestand/kickstand is up

**Once Started**

Make sure you have your gear handy once you start it so you can get on the bike and ride it around for a bit to charge the battery.  It's difficult to say how long you would need to ride to charge the batter due to the unknown state of the battery.

If push starting your bike works to get it started at least you can now begin to focus on the kick starter issue.